# How to call MS Access Parameter queries using VBA dynamic SQL SELECT statements

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I've searched MSDN, StackOverflow, SQLServer Central and too many sites to mention. I’ve been trying for a couple of days to find a way to execute parameter queries in MS Access using dynamic SQL SELECT statements in Excel VBA code. The system I’m using works extremely well with SQL Server TVFs, but I have to convert it to Access due to losing server support. The VBA code starts by looping through an ‘input’ sheet in Excel picking up parameter values and function/query names that is used to build dynamic SQL SELECT statements. Here is the code that builds the connection and calls the Access Query for just one of the queries (there are 20) that requires only 1 input paramter:

```
Dim strSQL

' set up our connection
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\PathToDB Tables 2013-12-13.accdb;"
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open strConnection
' open the view and create the report
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
Application.ODBCTimeout = 0
conn.CommandTimeout = 0
strSQL = "select * FROM "
strSQL = strSQL & strFunction
strSQL = strSQL & " (" & strParameters & ");"
'strSQL = strSQL & strOrderBy
rs.Open strSQL, conn
```

The value in strSQL at this point is `SELECT * FROM Report_1_2_StaffAdds (#12/31/2013#);`

The error occurs in the line   rs.Open strSQL, conn
With the error message  ‘Syntax error in FROM clause.'

Here is the MS Access Query: (Query name is Report_1_2_StaffAdds)

`PARAMETERS [previous_month] DateTime;
SELECT [1_2_StaffAddsPart1].Unit, [1_2_StaffAddsPart1].Role, [1_2_StaffAddsPart1].Start_Date, [1_2_StaffAddsPart2].First_Worked, [1_2_StaffAddsPart2].Last_Worked, [1_2_StaffAddsPart1].Emp_Name, [1_2_StaffAddsPart1].Emp_Id, [1_2_StaffAddsPart2].Hours_to_Date
FROM 1_2_StaffAddsPart1 INNER JOIN 1_2_StaffAddsPart2 ON [1_2_StaffAddsPart1].Emp_Id = [1_2_StaffAddsPart2].Emp_Id;`

Any help will be much appreciated. I believe if I can get an answer to this, I can revise it to include up to 3 input parameters, depending on which Access query is being executed at a given time.

Comment: user3299120, please try to make sure your code is formatted after you post your question

Comment: Added MS-Access tag to your question, get the right people looking at your question

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're attempting to include the parameter value in the string which contains your `SELECT` statement.  However, I'm not sure whether I understand what you're trying to do, so I'll offer you a simple tested parameter query which opens a recordset from an `ADODB.Command` object.

This is the Immediate window output from the code below:

```vb
PARAMETERS which_date DateTime;
SELECT * FROM tblFoo
WHERE datetime_field = [which_date];
id            datetime_field
 27           2/11/2014 10:16:58 AM
```

Code:

```vb
Dim cmd As Object ' ADODB.Command
Dim conn As Object ' ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As Object ' ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConnection As String
Dim strSql As String

strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\share\Access\database1.mdb;"
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open strConnection

strSql = "PARAMETERS which_date DateTime;" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT * FROM tblFoo" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE datetime_field = [which_date];"
Debug.Print strSql

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = strSql
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, CDate("2/11/2014 10:16:58 AM"))
With rs
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        Debug.Print "id", "datetime_field"
        Debug.Print !id, !datetime_field
    End If
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much HansUp! I'm going to give this a whirl and I'll post again to let you know. FYI, all the filtering and processing is done by multiple queries in the DB as parameters (all are dates) are passed in so a simple select statement pulls the correct recordset. Thanks again!

Comment: HansUp, this works like a charm. I had a little bit of revision so it would use referenced variables, but you made my day! Thank you so very much!! This shows I need to study up a lot more on ADO/DAO programming!!